# IWDFDevice::CreateWdfFile returns ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION?

Tags: windows-7, device-driver, sensors, umdf

I am writing a UMDF sensor driver for a device that connects to the system via Bluetooth and is accessible as an HID input device.  I saw the "Sensor Development Kit" sample driver and noticed that it works with the Freescale hardware via HID also though it connects to the system via USB.  Is there any difference in the way the UMDF driver communicates with the device in case it connects to the system via Bluetooth?  For some reason, I find that the call to `CreateWdfFile` returns `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` even when I have the device paired with the system.  I am able to access the device directly via HID just fine.

In the INF for the driver I have specified the hardware ID like so - `HID\VID_1234&PID_5678` (haven't used the actual IDs here).  Is this sufficient for the UMDF framework to determine which driver it should use further down the stack?  Or is there something else that one needs to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this one myself.  Turns out I wasn't using the correct hardware ID.  On a whim I looked up what hardware IDs the bluetooth device had been registered with under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID` and used another ID that had been given there and voila! - `IWDFDevice::CreateWdfFile` worked! :)  And sure enough, this is described quite clearly on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa938560.aspx).  So, all's good!